# Python Launcher Mac

Tags: python, macos, launcher

On my mac I am trying to make a `Python script` open by default in the `Python Launcher`.

I left click on the script and select *"open with"* and select the Launcher. Every-time I do this `Terminal` pops up, the Launcher window appears briefly. Then a messages pops up in a window: *"Python Launcher can only run certain scripts try another."*

Something along those line (the message has stop popping up since the first time I tried it but the script still doesn't run). I tried everything, GUIs, and basic scripts (like `print "Hello World"`). None work!

I tried doing the same thing on other computer and I get the same problem. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Does your script use a shebang line:

```
  #!/path/to/executable/python2.6
```

And does it have execute permissions?

```
 chmod +x path_to_file.py
```

It should run OK like this.

Comment: How do I do that I am new to python

Comment: Typed in exactly what you told me and substituted path_to_file.py with the file path and name and nothing happened

Comment: for the first part, you'll need to find python on your system, I'm guessing it should be: "#!/usr/local/bin/python" THIS MUST BE THE FIRST LINE OF THE SCRIPT

Comment: Sorry, just realised - on OSX it should be "#!/usr/bin/python"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Anaconda, Launcher is now deprecated, so your approach will have to change anyway. It has been replaced by Navigator.

Make sure you have updated Anaconda within terminal using

```
conda update conda
```

Then, you can install Navigator with

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

You will see a new icon show up that functions much the way Launcher used to. Your script will now have to be tied to it instead of launcher, assuming you figured that out with previous commenters' help.